# Not able to upload video file size greater than 500kb to Linux server in Android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to upload video file from android emulator, Genymotion and Mobile Device in Titanium Appcelerator.

***I am getting success when I upload small files capturing from emulator around about 200-300kb is working fine. its uploading and getting response from server.***

**When I am trying to upload file around 3-5MB then I am not getting response from server.** 
Some times I am getting response too late after 2-4 minutes and file was get uploaded at that time. But frequently its not uploaded and not getting response anymore.

I tried different code posted on web but did not get luck 100%.

In the log for on data stream I can see process 0-1 but for big file its stopped at .9999x, it is not reaching at 1.

```
[INFO] :   ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: 0.9998882582315288 
[INFO] :   ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: 0.9999253846335128 
[INFO] :   ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: 0.9999625110354967 
[INFO] :   ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: 0.9999996374374807
```

here is my sample code for testing.

**Titanium Button Click**

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
    action : Ti.Android.ACTION_PICK,
    type : "video/*"
});

intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

$.index.activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(ei) {
    if (ei.error) {
        alert("Error");
    } else {
        var dataUri = ei.intent.data;

        var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient(/*{enableKeepAlive:false}*/);
        xhr.setTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://gaurangchhatbar.in/ws/apitest/videouploadcode.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        xhr.onerror = function(ex) {
            alert(ex.error);
        };
        xhr.onload = function() {
            alert(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onsendstream = function(ex) {
            Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + ex.progress);
        };
        var filename = "UploadedFile-" + (new Date()).toString();
        filename = filename.replace(/\./g,"-");
        filename = filename.replace(/\:/g,"-") + ".mp4";
        Ti.API.info(filename);
        var source = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(dataUri);
        var fileData = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(), filename);

        source.copy(fileData.nativePath);
        if (fileData.exists()) {
            var fileContent = fileData.read();
            if (fileContent)
                xhr.send({
                    video_path : fileContent,
                    action : "uploadvideo"
                });
            else
                alert('Did not get any data back from file content');
        } else
            alert('Did not get a file data for : ' + dataUri);
    }
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
$target_path = "video/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['video_path']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_path']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    return "success";
} else{
    return "falied!";
}
```

I tried native android application to upload file from link : [Android Native App for Upload File to Server](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-video-to-server-using-php/)

It is working great.

Can any one know why response taking too much time? or let me know if I forgot anything.

I am working on


```
Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.5.0.201602170821
Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA
Alloy Project
Mac OS X El Capitan
Version 10.11.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the onsendstream() progress on android is just wrong (way too fast). I've reported this already as a bug here:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20483

Could it be that you are just confused by the sendstream callback and your code is all fine?

Comment: It's a bug and I've posted a solution to your issue! Still need to do some testing before I can create a PR. But you can add two lines and build yourself a working SDK with this solution https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20483?focusedCommentId=385890&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-385890 if you need a fix right away

Comment: Thanks Nils and miga, I was downloaded and tested it in SDK 5.3.0.v20160513184909 but also it not solve the problem. Can you provide me some help how to build working SDK with provided solution.